# MySQL syntax error after importing from local database django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've developed my site and database using local server and local installation of mysql. now I've currently setup a actual server and now that I wanted to export my local database and imported via phpmyadmin I give this error:

```
SQL query:



CREATE TABLE `account_emailconfirmation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `sent` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `email_address_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `key` (`key`),
  KEY `account_ema_email_address_id_5b7f8c58_fk_account_emailaddress_id` (`email_address_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ema_email_address_id_5b7f8c58_fk_account_emailaddress_id` FOREIGN KEY (`email_address_id`) REFERENCES `account_emailaddress` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
  `sent` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,' at line 3
```

what is wrong?
I tried to exclude this particular table but i had same error for some of other tables too.

versions:
mysql local: 5.7
mysql on web: 5.5

Comment: Are you sure you've posted the SQL that produces this error? [I couldn't reproduce this error...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31ba27/1/0)

Comment: @RiggsFolly the strange thing is since tables created using django I didn't write even one single SQL line. how can it be wrong when everything is good in localserver?

Comment: @MaxU some other answer mentioned that datetime shouldn't have length (which is 6 in here) and this is the problem. but how can django itself write this wrong?

Comment: AFAIK `datetime(6)` should be understood by MySQL 5.7+, but not by earlier releases...